# Removing a Forward Slash from my Data - Using Replace Function mysql3

Tags: sqlite

I am converting a BLOB file to a CSV file using mysqlite3. Once the conversion is completed I have forward slashes in my date data,  and characters of : in my time data.

Using the replace function i was able to remove the : characters from the Time data but was NOT able to remove the forward slashes.

After much research i have read that using multiple forward slashes should work however this was not the case for me.

The following part of the expression is what i am having trouble with (the date part only)

```
select REPLACE(date(eventdate/1000,'unixepoch'), '/' ,' ') as EventDate
       ,REPLACE(Time(eventdate/1000,'unixepoch', ':' ,' ') as EventTime
```

As started above the removal of : is working OK just not the removal of the / characters,  How do i remove the / characters from my date. The date is currently dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: What do you mean:  *The date is currently dd/mm/yyyy*? What is `eventdate`?

Comment: Correct - when i convert the Blob File to CSV file the end result of the eventdate is in the format of dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function [`date()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) succeeds it will return a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` so it will not contain any forward slashes and the `replace()` function will do nothing because there is nothing to replace.
If you have dates in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` and you want to remove the forward slashes then apply `replace()` to them directly without the use of `date()`.

If you have an integer column `eventdate` which you want to convert to date and format it like `DD MM YYYY` then you can do it with [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
strftime('%d %m %Y',date(12345612345/1000,'unixepoch'))
```